# MongoDB $lookup on array of objects with reference objectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, collections, lookup

I have Orders collection and iam getting the data from it as shown below:

```
 [
  {
    "_id": "628216b7b30bb8aa80c8fd1a",
    "promotionsDetails": {
      "companyTotalPrice": 27,
      "promotionsData": [
        {
          "_id": "621de063bb5f9f0bf510897f",
          "price": 27,
          "companyId": "621dd85eb45ca2ae292d9a36"
        },
        {
          "_id": "621de063bb5f9f0bf510897d",
          "price": 19,
          "companyId": "621dd85eb45ca2ae292d9a32"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "628214fcb30bb8aa80c8fd18",
    "promotionsDetails": {
      "companyTotalPrice": 46,
      "promotionsData": [
        {
          "_id": "621de063bb5f9f0bf510897f",
          "price": 46,
          "companyId": "621dd85eb45ca2ae292d9a32",
        }
      ]
    },
  }
]
```

what I am trying to do is to get the company details from the companies collection using the  companyId objectId in each object in the array, like below:

```
    [
  {
    "_id": "628216b7b30bb8aa80c8fd1a",
    "promotionsDetails": {
      "companyTotalPrice": 27,
      "promotionsData": [
        {
          "_id": "621de063bb5f9f0bf510897f",
          "price": 27,
          "companyId": "621dd85eb45ca2ae292d9a36",
          "companyData": { "title": "..." }
        },
        {
          "_id": "621de063bb5f9f0bf510897d",
          "price": 19,
          "companyId": "621dd85eb45ca2ae292d9a32",
          "companyData": { "title": "..." }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "628214fcb30bb8aa80c8fd18",
    "promotionsDetails": {
      "companyTotalPrice": 46,
      "promotionsData": [
        {
          "_id": "621de063bb5f9f0bf510897f",
          "price": 46,
          "companyId": "621dd85eb45ca2ae292d9a32",
          "companyData": { "title": "..." }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

i have tried to use lookup and pipeline, but I'm not getting the desired result, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, to make it more clear take a look at [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yRmJgqaCIgc)

```html
db.Orders.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$promotionsDetails.promotionsData"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Company",
      "localField": "promotionsDetails.promotionsData.companyId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "promotionsDetails.promotionsData.companyData"
    }
  },
  
])
```

Comment: as nimrod said, yes its changing the structure of the object, but for me I don't mind. thanks for your answer!

Comment: You can play with $group to put the structure back if needed. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

Actuality `$lookup` supports arrays, so there is no need to `$unwind` and change the structure. This will return your expected results:

```
db.Orders.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Company",
      localField: "promotionsDetails.promotionsData.companyId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "companyfullData"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "promotionsDetails.promotionsData": {
        $map: {
          input: "$promotionsDetails.promotionsData",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                companyData: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$companyfullData",
                    {$indexOfArray: ["$companyfullData.id", "$$this.id"]}
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$unset: "companyfullData"}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L7ZO9v1Bovr)

Comment: actually it works but its not filling the company data inside companyData object, its filling the data inside promotionsData array item and overrides any exist field with the same name

Comment: Updated to insert into `companyData`

Comment: nimrod, thanks for the solution, exactly what I was looking for. You were very close, just a small error in $indexOfArray. $companyfullData.id should match $$this.companyId instead of $$this.id which is the promotion id. My fix $indexOfArray: ["$companyfullData._id", "$$this.companyId"].  https://mongoplayground.net/p/Myci5IHuy8S